# How to count returned rows number without using get_result() in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlnd

I am using GoDaddy shared hosting plan and looks like there are some issues on using the `mysqli` and `mysqlnd` in all versions of PHP 7,7.1,7.2, and 7.3 on their hosting.

After many tries on changing and updating PHP versions and modules I, eventually, gave up using the `get_result()` function as I am getting this error

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

What other function can I use instead of the`get_result()` to make sure there are rows in the `$result`?

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                 $items[] = $row;
             }
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
```

Comment: Verify you're for sure using mysqlnd as your Client Library with mysqli, that function only exists with the Native Driver. That should be the default post 5.4.x, but just make sure.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I already did all of these. still same isuue is happening. so I want to change my code

Answer (score -2):

Try using `$stmt->num_rows` and get rid of the get_result

```
 if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
 $stmt->execute();
 if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())         { 
 $items[] = $row;
 }
 $stmt->free_result(); $stmt->close(); 
 } 
$conn->close();
 }
```

Comment: Thansk Adam , now no error happening but I am getting empty array back! on `echo json_encode($items);`

Comment: var_dump on $row. See if the data is getting brought from the database

Comment: `num_rows` is not going to work if you don't fetch the result!